# How can I inject an application shared ViewModel throught Hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, viewmodel, dagger-hilt

I need to share a view model with most activities in my app

At first, I tried this way

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class SharedViewModel @Inject constructor() : ViewModel(){
    ...
}
```

```kotlin
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ActivityA : BaseActivity(){
   private val sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel by viewModels()
}
```

```kotlin
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ActivityB : BaseActivity(){
   private val sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel by viewModels()
}
```

It was built successfully, but Hilt actually created a new instance for each activity.
I want ActivityA & ActivityB & more Activity to share the same instance of SharedViewModel.

So I changed to this way

```kotlin
@Singleton
class SharedViewModel @Inject constructor() : ViewModel(){
    ...
}
```

```kotlin
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ActivityA : BaseActivity(){
    @Inject
    lateinit var sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel
}
```

```kotlin
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ActivityB : BaseActivity(){
    @Inject
    lateinit var sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel
}
```

This way it works, but I wonder whether I code appropriately, or is there a better way to make it happen?

Answer (score 0):

You could just create an Application scoped Singleton class. Which is not exactly a recommended approach to holding UI state.

Create a module and add a provider for your class

```kotlin
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class) //scoped to application
object AppStateModule {

    @Singleton //initialized once in whole app scope
    @Provides
    fun provideYourClass(): YourClass {
        return YourClass()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, which is the recommended approach to holding UI state through Application scope.

Comment: UI state should be held by `ViewModels` in android. If you have shared data that is used all over your application, it is better to persist the data in Preference or Database.

Singletons are valid use-case if it's an application state instead of a UI state and you want it to be temporary. You need to be aware of issues like memory leaks.